# Auth error when deploying Cloud FireStore cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Can firestore security rules interfere with cloud functions? I keep getting this error when I try to deploy a cloud function on my app:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
}
```

Here's the code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(5);
exports.addPointsOnDropOffCreation = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}/dropOffs/{dropOffId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const dropOffData = snapshot.data();
    if (dropOffData) {
      const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${dropOffData.userId}`)
      return userRef.update({ points: increment })
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
```

I've run firebase login  to check and I am on the correct account. I've been cracking away at this problem for two days with no real progress. I ran the example cloud functions they provide in the docs to test that they'd work and I was able to deploy them. I feel like I'm just doing something wrong, either in this function or in the security rules that govern the DB.

Edit: per a Redditor's comment, I'm adding the full debug logs below:

```
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.053Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.055Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.055Z] [iam] checking project scrapitapp-74f38 for permissions ["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","firebase.projects.get"]
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.057Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38:testIamPermissions  
 {"permissions":["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","firebase.projects.get"]}
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.225Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:14 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","server-timing":"gfet4t7; dur=88","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.227Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/serviceAccounts/scrapitapp-74f38@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:testIamPermissions  
 {"permissions":["iam.serviceAccounts.actAs"]}
[2020-11-16T17:21:14.326Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:14 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}

=== Deploying to 'scrapitapp-74f38'...

i  deploying functions 
[2020-11-16T17:21:16.187Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled... 
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled... 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.235Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.236Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.236Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/services/cloudbuild.googleapis.com  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.493Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:17 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.511Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:17 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.540Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:17 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.542Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/adminSdkConfig  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.667Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:17 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.670Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://runtimeconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/configs  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:17.810Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:17 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
i  functions: packaged functions (24.22 KB) for uploading 
[2020-11-16T17:21:18.162Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/locations/-/functions  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:18.589Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:18 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:18.594Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:18.961Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:18 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:18.963Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-32278de5-25cb-4c33-90a2-094b4d597f04/21ea53f0-8f02-4766-baf0-6a8ea6f41d6b.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-645504965265@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1605549078&Signature=AZuP%2BLAEfU3k5865jX2KtH5%2Fqm5vFTqsD7VSGu6giuhaEhJaw3p9b14D9L2C%2Fibz5RL6gJZXTjqDFi7LxHxIy96IqAoKCVZ08Q8XaAYf%2F0uF1aACBTYolVOlArS%2BXmbBXpjhm%2BUmaEP115UhO2i8jIo3nsL8Ugg0KXFCK%2BNnZF5Q2thpynQdnbRYXP8Azv4xI7WrWCPrjIC1iyEzo4sBVcpMGX7LJIkZ0ChwFagp6OTnTs9aYIr4m3ttcZ2ibowKOM%2FY4Riix4skOSCM6yWGjBgyf6BJkduex%2B7cVDO0NDzPyiEUYNaQ19jBpqTd92%2BLC9m36Z1sOQzJWMHq0pwjVw%3D%3D  
 <request body omitted>
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.121Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"x-guploader-uploadid":"ABg5-UxJe067SCYCENF3jBU6SBtzhiF6ihkDNnWl3jD9h7_vrKwyuGNmkFVQWvc3Z0VY-W0XbUnV2uniNgciPAi3kioBXVVPAA","etag":"\"e10bd5ff844f59e577da5aad37dcffd6\"","x-goog-generation":"1605547279105924","x-goog-metageneration":"1","x-goog-hash":"crc32c=wn/cww==, md5=4QvV/4RPWeV32lqtN9z/1g==","x-goog-stored-content-length":"24806","x-goog-stored-content-encoding":"identity","vary":"Origin","content-length":"0","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:19 GMT","server":"UploadServer","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""}
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully 
i  functions: creating Node.js 12 function addPointsOnDropOffCreation(us-central1)... 
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.124Z] Trigger is:  {"eventTrigger":{"resource":"projects/scrapitapp-74f38/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}/dropOffs/{dropOffId}","eventType":"providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create","service":"firestore.googleapis.com"}}
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.126Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/scrapitapp-74f38/locations/us-central1/functions  
 {"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-32278de5-25cb-4c33-90a2-094b4d597f04/21ea53f0-8f02-4766-baf0-6a8ea6f41d6b.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-645504965265@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1605549078&Signature=AZuP%2BLAEfU3k5865jX2KtH5%2Fqm5vFTqsD7VSGu6giuhaEhJaw3p9b14D9L2C%2Fibz5RL6gJZXTjqDFi7LxHxIy96IqAoKCVZ08Q8XaAYf%2F0uF1aACBTYolVOlArS%2BXmbBXpjhm%2BUmaEP115UhO2i8jIo3nsL8Ugg0KXFCK%2BNnZF5Q2thpynQdnbRYXP8Azv4xI7WrWCPrjIC1iyEzo4sBVcpMGX7LJIkZ0ChwFagp6OTnTs9aYIr4m3ttcZ2ibowKOM%2FY4Riix4skOSCM6yWGjBgyf6BJkduex%2B7cVDO0NDzPyiEUYNaQ19jBpqTd92%2BLC9m36Z1sOQzJWMHq0pwjVw%3D%3D","name":"projects/scrapitapp-74f38/locations/us-central1/functions/addPointsOnDropOffCreation","entryPoint":"addPointsOnDropOffCreation","labels":{"deployment-tool":"cli-firebase"},"runtime":"nodejs12","environmentVariables":{"FIREBASE_CONFIG":"{\"projectId\":\"scrapitapp-74f38\",\"databaseURL\":\"https://scrapitapp-74f38.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"scrapitapp-74f38.appspot.com\",\"locationId\":\"us-central\"}"},"eventTrigger":{"resource":"projects/scrapitapp-74f38/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}/dropOffs/{dropOffId}","eventType":"providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create","service":"firestore.googleapis.com"}}
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.517Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:19 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.534Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:19.673Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:19 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:21.680Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:21.817Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:21 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:23.820Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:23.996Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:23 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:26.000Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:26.139Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:26 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:28.142Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:28.239Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:28 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:30.243Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:30.385Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:30 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:32.390Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:32.532Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:32 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:34.535Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:34.636Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:34 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:36.639Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:36.765Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:36 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:38.767Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:38.875Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:38 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:40.878Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:40.988Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:40 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:42.992Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:43.119Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:43 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:45.122Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:45.240Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:45 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:47.243Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:47.346Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:47 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:49.349Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:49.455Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:49 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:51.458Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:51.577Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:51 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-11-16T17:21:53.582Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/c2NyYXBpdGFwcC03NGYzOC91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hZGRQb2ludHNPbkRyb3BPZmZDcmVhdGlvbi9rU3A0UXZsTWhaTQ  
 
[2020-11-16T17:21:53.727Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Mon, 16 Nov 2020 17:21:53 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
```

Comment: How are you deploying the cloud Function?

Comment: And are you getting the error on the execution or while deploying?

Comment: I'm deploying the function using: firebase deploy --only functions

The error occurs while deploying.

Comment: could you make sure you are running the command while logged with a project owner?

Answer (score 1):

> Can firestore security rules interfere with cloud functions?

Security rules only affect code using the web and mobile SDKs.  They do not affect code using the Firebase Admin SDK.  It doesn't matter where that code is running - if it was initilaized with a service account (which it will be when you run `initializeApp()`), then it bypasses all security rules.

If you're getting that error message *during deployment*, that has nothing to do with the code itself or any security rules.  That's the Firebase CLI telling you that something else is wrong with your account or project.  If the error message is not helpful to you, reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.

Comment: Ok, that's very helpful for at least triaging the problem. Will share the resolution here when I eventually find it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, any luck with the resolution?